# `GeneratePresignedUrl` needs AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Currently In my android project I am using `GeneratePresignedUrl` to get the link of a private file from `Amazon s3`. it worked fine few times on main thread, after it started giving `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. My question is does `GeneratePresignedUrl` needs `Asynctask`? Or is it a bug ?

Android Aws sdk version 2.2.20 (new version).

Code: from Util.java

```
public static URL getSignedUrl(Context context,String imageString){
    URL url=null;

           try {
               System.out.println("Generating pre-signed URL.");
               java.util.Date expiration = new java.util.Date();
               long milliSeconds = expiration.getTime();
               milliSeconds += 1000 * 60 * 60; // Add 1 hour.
               expiration.setTime(milliSeconds);
                sGenerateSignedUrl = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(Constants.BUCKET, imageString);
                sGenerateSignedUrl.setMethod(HttpMethod.GET);
                sGenerateSignedUrl.setExpiration(expiration);
                url = getS3Client(context.getApplicationContext()).generatePresignedUrl(sGenerateSignedUrl);


                System.out.println("Pre-Signed URL = " + url.toString());
               //if(url!=null)
               return url;
           }catch (AmazonServiceException exception) {
                System.out.println("Caught an AmazonServiceException, " +
                        "which means your request made it " +
                        "to Amazon S3, but was rejected with an error response " +
                        "for some reason.");
                System.out.println("Error Message: " + exception.getMessage());
                System.out.println("HTTP  Code: " + exception.getStatusCode());
                System.out.println("AWS Error Code:" + exception.getErrorCode());
                System.out.println("Error Type:    " + exception.getErrorType());
                System.out.println("Request ID:    " + exception.getRequestId());
            } catch (AmazonClientException ace) {
                System.out.println("Caught an AmazonClientException, " +
                        "which means the client encountered " +
                        "an internal error while trying to communicate" +
                        " with S3, " +
                        "such as not being able to access the network.");
                System.out.println("Error Message: " + ace.getMessage());
            }


    return url;
}
```

Calling Above method like this.

```
URL url = Util.getSignedUrl(getContext().getApplicationContext(),"image path string");
```

It worked really fine 20+ times. And later started reporting `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Comment: My solution was to just catch the `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. im loading some images from S3 so if it is thrown I just catch it and do nothing. what was your solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`AmazonS3.generatePresignedUrl` itself doesn't make network request. However to create a presigned Url, it needs credentials from `AmazonS3` client, and credentials are provided from `CognitoCacheingCredentialsProvider` which makes a network calls to STS and Cognito Identity Service. That's the cause of `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. If credentials are cached from previous calls, then such exception won't be thrown. Hope this explains.

Comment: Thank you. but uploading object do not require Async task right ? I mean using Amzons3 client with credentials.

Comment: Anything that makes a network request has to be called from a background thread. So yes, AmazonS3.putObject requires AsyncTask (or background thread). An alternative is to use TransferUtility which takes care of this for you.

Comment: Yeah. I am using transferutility only.

Comment: Yangfan you are right but how can we handle this?
I have list of image on amazon so need to add asyncTask which takes too much loading to my app.
Please help me to out from this

Answer (score 0):

You should almost always run network operations on a thread or as an asynchronous task.
To avoid NetworkOnMainThreadException, Add in you class

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Comment: I don't know `GeneratePresignedUrl` needs AsyncTask really, That's why I posted. If it needs Thread or Asynctask I will put around them. However, putting the lines you suggested skip the networkeonmainthreadexception.Ok but does it still block Ui?

Answer (score 0):

- Use latest Aws SDK version
- Pass Region in AmazonS3Client with credie

fun generateURL(
objectKey: String,
ACCESS_KEY: String,
SECRET_KEY: String,
BUCKET_NAME:String
): URL? {

```
    val creds = BasicAWSCredentials(ACCESS_KEY ,SECRET_KEY)
    val s3 = AmazonS3Client(
        creds, Region.getRegion(
            Regions.US_EAST_2
        )
    )
    val expires = Date(Date().time + 1000 * 60 * 60)

    val keyFile = objectKey
    val generatePresignedUrlRequest = GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(
       BUCKET_NAME,
        keyFile
    )
    generatePresignedUrlRequest.expiration = expires
    val url: URL = s3.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest)

    return url
}
```

}